# notice after entering a function in template.php

Tags: theming, hooks

I get the following notices on every page:

```
Notice: Undefined index: node in myZen_preprocess_page() (line 242 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupalH1/sites/all/themes/myZen/template.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in myZen_preprocess_page() (line 242 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupalH1/sites/all/themes/myZen/template.php).
Notice: Undefined index: node in myZen_preprocess_page() (line 246 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupalH1/sites/all/themes/myZen/template.php).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in myZen_preprocess_page() (line 246 of /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupalH1/sites/all/themes/myZen/template.php).
```

I put the function I need to use the files page--content-type, and is as follows:

```
function myZen_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
   if ($vars['node']->type == 'mappe'){
     $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__mappe';

    }
  else if ($vars['node']->type == 'fatti_e_risorse'){
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__fatti_e_risorse';

  }

  }
```

Can I disable notices or fix this? thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That notification is displayed because the `node` key of the `$vars` array is not always defined in `hook_preprocess_page()` function.

Use the following code, which first checks if the `node` key exists and then continues. It also uses the `switch` statement, which is easier to read if you only need to check the node type and use one condition:

```
function myZen_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    switch ($vars['node']->type) {
      case 'mappe':
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__mappe';
        break;

      case 'fatti_e_risorse':
        $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__fatti_e_risorse';
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked for another function I was running. Thanks!